# CasperJS click google search button, this.evaluate() javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, phantomjs, casperjs

I am now learning Casperjs, I want to mimic the google search( 1. fill in the content 2. click the button; not use 'fill'). The javascript code works in my Chrome console, but doesn't work in my CasperJS. Any ideas, complaints or same experience as me ?

Waiting for answers!

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    logLevel:"info",
    verbose:true,
});

casper.start("https://www.google.fr/",function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        document.getElementById("gbqfq").value="phantomjs";
        document.getElementById("gbqfsa").click();
    });
    //this.fill('form[action="/search"]',{q:'phantomjs'},true);
}).then(function(){
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
});

casper.run();
```

Answer (score 2):

Google builds the page differently depending on the user agent string, so you need to set one from a desktop browser.

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    logLevel:"debug",
    verbose:true,
    pageSettings: {
        userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36"
    }
});
```

You can then change the value, but nothing happens if you try to invoke the `click()` function although it is present on the element.

```
casper.start("https://www.google.fr/").then(function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        var qq = document.querySelector("input[name=q]"),
            qb = document.querySelector("button[name=btnK]"),
            iq = document.getElementById("gbqfq"),
            ib = document.getElementById("gbqfba");
        __utils__.echo("Fields: "+JSON.stringify({
            qq: !!qq, // true
            qb: !!qb, // false w/o UA, true w/ UA
            iq: !!iq, // false w/o UA, true w/ UA
            ib: !!ib, // false w/o UA, true w/ UA
        }));
        qq.value="phantomjs";
        //iq.value="phantomjs";
        qb.click(); // nothing happens
        ib.click(); // nothing happens
    });
}).then(function(){
    this.echo(this.getTitle());
    this.capture("result.png");
});
```

I couldn't find a way to click the button from the page context. So this code does not produce the result page. You can either use `fill` or `sendKeys` because those invoke the event handling on the search field which automatically (instant) does the search. Also you don't need to set the submit parameter to `true` in the `fill` function because the search is instantaneous.